# Proof of property of a function with a 'simple zero'

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, solution-verification

This is a question I've been struggling with for a while and I managed to write an answer, but I'm not sure about it.Would highly appreciate if you could let me know if my proof for both implications are correct. If not what are the corrections I need to make. Thanks in advance.

[image: Question]

[image: Answer1]

[image: Answer2]

Comment: On your first page you establish $f'(x_0)=g(x_0)$ by assuming $f'(t)$ is continuous at $x_0$ which isn't clear. You have a proof $f'(x)$ exists for $x\not=x_0$; for $x_0$ just write down $\frac{f(x)-f(x_0}{x-x_0}=g(x)$ and use the given continuity of $g$ to establish the existence and value of $f'(x_0)$.

Comment: On your second page I see no justification that L'HR can be applied, and I am pretty sure that it's not necessary anyway. [If your denominator in L'HR is $x-x_0$ then almost certainly L'HR is unnecessary and the mere definition of the derivative is what you need.]